# Google Survey Opt-in giving 404 error in DevTools Console Tab

Tags: javascript, google-surveys

Is there a reason why this would give 404 error in the DevTools console tab? Like the page loads 100% fine but the survey opt-in popup fails to show and gives 404 (I did try to contact Google but they don't seem to be able to figure this out)

This is the code I used, and I even tried hard coding the date (aka writing "2018-09-08" with and without the " ") - what it does it takes today's date and adds 7 days to it then formats it to yyyy-mm-dd

please help!

```
<!-- BEGIN GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn"
  async defer>
</script>

<script>
var sevenDaysFromNow = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7);
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
  window.renderOptIn = function() { 
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
        {
          // REQUIRED
          "merchant_id":xxxxxxxx,
          "order_id": "{BOOKINGNUMBER}",
          "email": "{EMAIL}",
          "delivery_country": "CA",
          "estimated_delivery_date": formatDate(sevenDaysFromNow),

          // OPTIONAL
          "opt_in_style": "CENTER_DIALOG"
        }); 
     });
  }
</script>
<!-- END GCR Opt-in Module Code -->



<!-- BEGIN GCR Language Code -->
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en_US'
  };
</script>
<!-- END GCR Language Code -->
```

Comment: I'm getting this same issue to this day in production. Verified the domain matches. Did you crack this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this using some development environment, it may return 404 when the domain if different from what's registered at the Merchant Center. It's to avoid someone else affecting your site's ratings.

Test the modal on the production domain, it should work.